# Express Server - Connect with Another API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Trying to create an express server that passes all request to another api, and return its values to the user (at react project).

For example;
When I make a request from my react app as; /api/blabla

Express server will take it and make a request to [www.blabla.com/api/blabla](http://www.blabla.com/api/blabla) with all body informations. And i'll add my own headers on it.

But it didnt work as I expected.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
// Allow cross-origin
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('*', (req, res) => {
    axios.post(`https://blabla.com/api/businesse`, req.body,{
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Authorization": "Bearer Token-001"
            }
        }
    )
});

const PORT = 5050;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

1. problem: i can not use the current path to use in my api connection.
2. problem: it didnt use body that i send from react app.

Comment: why are you adding response headers (specifically `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) in a request?

Answer (score 0):

Why does Axios seem such a popular choice for this lately? It really is a terrible proxy.

Try out [express-http-proxy](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy) instead

```js
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.post(
  '*',
  proxy('blabla.com', {
    https: true,
    proxyReqPathResolver: () => '/api/businesse',
    proxyReqOptDecorator: (options) => {
      Object.assign(options, {
        headers: {
          ...options.headers,
          accept: 'application/json',
          authorization: 'Bearer Token-001',
        },
      });
      return options;
    },
  })
);
```